# Custom design changes to Airflow UI

Tags: user-interface, airflow, airflow-webserver

I would like to add some custom changes to UI in my airflow instance. For example I would like to add some links and next to every day there could be some icon where I can click through to the gitlab repo with source code of the DAG.

So in particular I would like to make airflow more user friendly for my own specific needs. Is there a way to make something like this? I heard something of plugins which I am use for custom operators but can I use it also in this way?

Thank you for your suggestions. I will add a picture to emphasize what I am actually trying to achieve.

[image: Example image]

I tried to read through some articles but It does not look that someone tried to do the same thing like me.

Comment: Check this out https://medium.com/@caxefaizan/creating-custom-ui-for-airflow-7021c851631c